# php sort post data into arrays

Tags: php, arrays, post

I would like to get some input values from post and store them in an array. Here are my input elements which are repeatable fields:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="itemquantity[]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="buyproduct[]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="freeproduct[]" />
```

When i submit the form and print_r i get the following (the fields have been repeated):

```
Array ( [itemquantity] => Array ( 
                               [0] => 1 
                               [1] => 4 
                               ) 
        [buyproduct] => Array ( 
                               [0] => 2 
                               [1] => 5 
                              ) 
        [freeproduct] => Array ( 
                                [0] => 3 
                                [1] => 6 
                               )
```

How can i group them by each repeated filed?

So for example i would expect an output like this:

```
Array(
  Array [0](
    [itemquantity] => 1
    [buyquantity] => 2
    [freeproduct] => 3
  )
  Array [1](
    [itemquantity] => 4
    [buyquantity] => 5
    [freeproduct] => 6
  )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use `foreach`-loop

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($_POST['itemquantity'] as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = array(
        'itemquantity' => $v,
        'buyquantity' => $_POST['buyquantity'][$k],
        'freeproduct' => $_POST['freeproduct'][$k],
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can more easily use this in PHP:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item1[itemquantity]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item1[buyproduct]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item1[freeproduct]" />

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item2[itemquantity]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item2[buyproduct]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="item2[freeproduct]" />
```

This will become this in PHP post variable:

```
Array(
    Array [item1](
        [itemquantity] => 1
        [buyquantity] => 2
        [freeproduct] => 3
    )
    Array [item2](
        [itemquantity] => 4
        [buyquantity] => 5
        [freeproduct] => 6
    )
)
```

Comment: Using fixed names for different groups makes it a lot harder to add / remove groups dynamically. Using something like `name="items[1][buyproduct]"` would solve that.

Comment: then you can always double array it all, with just one name: `item[0][otemquantity]`. `$_POST['item']` will contain the array as required

Comment: I just added that :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (note the [][] in the element names)..

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="[][itemquantity]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="[][buyproduct]" />
<input type="text" class="form-control gettitles" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="[][freeproduct]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the existing `$_POST` data and rearrange it into a suitable structure. Loop through the `$_POST` data and populate a new array with the desired output, thus;

```
$output = array(); $i = 0;
foreach($_POST['itemquantity'] as $v) {
  $output[] = array(
    'itemquantity' => $v,
    'buyquantity' => $_POST['buyquantity'][$i],
    'freeproduct' => $_POST['freeproduct'][$i]
  );
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for or foreach loop. you can do something like this,

```
<?php
$a1 = array(1,2,3);
$a2 = array(4,5,6);
$new_array[] = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($a1); $i++){
    $new_array[$i]['a1'] = $a1[$i];
    $new_array[$i]['a2'] = $a2[$i];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```